# syntax error: identifier 'POMAP'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

Today I faced surprising compile error while using VS2015 preview. The error that complain is this. 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ImageHlp.h(1885): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'POMAP'`

Its complaining about its own file. here is the part from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ImageHlp.h

```
struct _OMAP {
    ULONG  rva;
    ULONG  rvaTo;
} OMAP, *POMAP;

BOOL
IMAGEAPI
SymGetOmaps(
    _In_ HANDLE hProcess,
    _In_ DWORD64 BaseOfDll,
    _Out_ POMAP *OmapTo,
    _Out_ PDWORD64 cOmapTo,
    _Out_ POMAP *OmapFrom,
    _Out_ PDWORD64 cOmapFrom
    );
```

The issue is `typedef` missing from _OMAP struct declaration. I have just added the `typedef` in  struct declaration. then everything works fine. but my co-developers all need to do this change every-time.

Anyone knows a workaround to avoid this issue. is that a bug of VS2015?

Comment: same for me would be good to have a solution